# Что будет меньше потреблять ресурсы?

Tags: c, оптимизация

Сейчас изучаю динамические массивы. Дал себе задание: считать из файла данные в динамический массив структур . Как лучше выделять память? Есть 2 варианта:

1. Посчитать количество строк в файле и дать место под массив malloc'ом. Минусы этого метода, что по файлу надо пробигаться 2 раза: первый это подсчёт количества строк, второй заполнение массива.
2. При считывании из файла расширять выделяемую память realloc'ом. Минусы этого метода, что realloc - ресурсозатратное средство. Но можно немного обойти этот минус и выделять раз в 3 итерации сразу память для трёх элементов.

Итак, что же использовать лучше? Или возможно всё зависит от размера файла?
**UPD:**
 1. OC - Windows
 2. Формат данных в фалйе: Название(char)|количество(int)\n
И структура из двух элементов name(char[255]) и count(int). Кол-во данных не фиксированное, может быть как 100 элементов так и 1000. Или всё-таки ввести максимум и выделять максимум памяти вначале, а потом сокращать? Или узнать сколько весит 1 эелемент этой структуры, проверить размер файла, разделить его на вес 1го элемента и так мы получим кол-во элементов, для которых надо выделять память?

Comment: "Или возможно всё зависит от размера файла?" 

Или, возможно, зависит от того, чем Вы больше дорожите: ресурсами или скоростью.

Comment: Можно использовать vector. Или посмотреть его реализацию. Допустим если писать свой vector, то можно при добавлении элемента, если достигли предела выделенной памяти, то выделять еще память с запасом и так далее. Получится надо будет выделять память не под каждый айтем, но зато будет немного больше памяти использвано.

Comment: @iproger, попробуйте конкретизировать задачу (похоже, в такой постановке она не вызывает живого обсуждения).

- Какой формат данных в файле?

- Что из него Вы хотите хранить в памяти?

- О какой ОС идет речь?

Если размер структуры фиксирован и в ней нет указателей на динамически размещаемые элементы, то в Linux я бы посмотрел размер файла в байтах, прикинул максимальное количество структур, которые могут из него получиться, выделил под них память одним вызовом malloc и за одно чтение файла заполнил этот массив структур, а потом вызвал realloc для его сокращения до актуального размера.

Comment: @avp, спасибо, ответил апдейтом

Comment: @iproger, в винде не пишу.

Comment: посмотрел внимательно вопрос. Я правильно понимаю, что количество записей храниться в начале файла? Тогда вообще проблем не вижу.

С другой стороны, похоже, что размер структуры фиксированный - 260 байт. Поэтому, разделив размер файла на 260 можно получить очень хорошее значение для размера массива (оно будет чуточку больше - там заголовок непонятного размера)

Comment: @KoVadim, исходя из упоминания автором *количества строк*, следует думать, что наименование в файле вряд ли фиксированной длины.

Собственно в UPD написано,

    2. Формат данных в фалйе: Название(char)|количество(int)\n

что название от количества отделяется символом '|'.


Поэтому деление на 260 даст сильно заниженную оценку количества структур в памяти.

--

@iproger, не думаю, что формат структуры с фиксированным размером `name` это хорошее проектное решение.

Comment: Или я неправильно понял описание, или количество структур "количество(int)" хранится в заголовке?

Comment: количество это просто элемент структуры. Т.е. например наименование "Вода Кувака|100". Да, не получится делить размер файла ,чтобы узнать кол-во, т.к. наименование и кол-во разной длины

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а с чего вы взяли что "количество строк" == "размер файла" ?

яркий пример 2 файла в одном 2 строки в каждой 10 символов и втором 2 строки и в каждой 1000 символов...

у любого файла есть мета информация о размере, времени создания, времени чтения, etc...

1. узнаём размер файла
2. узнаём размер памяти
3. узнаём сколько свободно памяти
4. используем полученную инфу...

Comment: Мм, а как именно использовать данную информацию? Ну вот допустим размер файла 2МБ, свободно памяти 1ГБ. Какой вариант выбирать? Или просто в начале выделять столько памяти, сколько весит файл?

Comment: а если памяти 700мб а файл 4гб ?
зная размер файла, памяти, и объём свободной памяти прикидываем размер буфера (на вкус и цвет).


читаем sizeof("буфер") из файла, запоминаем позицию,
обрабатываем данные и снова читаем sizeof("буфер") из файла.

Answer (score 0):

1. Спрашиваеш у файловой системы размер файла в байтах.
2. просишь у malloc ровно столько байт
3. прочитываеш в этот чанк свой файл
4. считаешь число строк в памяти(число eol и \0)
5. просишь у malloc вот такого размер массива указателей на char сколько насчитал строк
6. однократным сканированием выставляеш указатели на начала строк и заменяеш все переводы на \0

Comment: мало того, что памяти выделиться в два раза больше, чем нужно, так и на 2 пункте можно получить oom или просто тихое рыдание винта (свопиться будет).

Comment: память выделится только на размер файла  байт + размер_ указателя*(число_переводов_строк+1)

4 пунт подсчёт , а не второе считывание.

Comment: @qulinxao, а зачем автору вообще вектор указателей на строки файла, если его цель массив структур, содержащих данные из строк файла?

Действительно, из одной строки получается одна структура в памяти, но хранить-то эти строки одновременно с построенными  структурами не требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Выделить сразу какой-то объём памяти (которого, скорее всего, хватит в большинстве случаев), если возникла нехватка - расширяем.

Посмотрите код фреймворка для юнит-тестирования CuTest, там своя реализация строк CuString примерно так и сделана.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать на базе односвязанного списка (или одномерным массивом с realloc). И читать посимвольно.
В псевдокоде примерно так:

> ```
> offset = 0
> while (!eof)
> {
>   while (fgetc() !=  \n); // читаем до конца строки
>
>   s.offset = offset
>   s.size = fseek() - offset
>   list_add(s)
>   offset = fseek()
> }
> ```

а потом по надобности читать из файла строку по нужному смещению

Comment: односвязный список (при условии, что на каждый элемент будет выделятся память) не будет оптимальным по использованию памяти. Дело в том, что просто так выделить 3 байта или 15 нельзя. Память все равно выделяется кратной как минимум 4 байтам (а то и все 16). Хвосты будут просто простаивать.

Comment: он будет неоптимальным, если длина строк в среднем по файлу >8 символов (для x86). Строки меньше 4 символов можно хранить в значении offset.
В простом случае все выравнено на 4: указатель на следующий элемент (4), смещение в файле (4/8), размер (4)

Comment: Пример готового кода, написанного на коленке
http://pastebin.com/wFHCETLC

Comment: @Veliant, а зачем автору вопроса список дескрипторов строк в файле? 

Он вроде бы написал

      Дал себе задание: считать из файла данные в динамический массив структур 

И при этом интересуется, какой из способов **построения массива** (с данными из файла) наименее ресурсозатратный.

--

А минимальный конечный расход памяти для задачи в Вашей интерпретации -- это массив из n + 1 элемента (n -- количество строк). Каждый элемент -- смещение. Последний элемент массива -- смещение на конец файла.

Длины строк хранить не надо. Длина i-ой строки вычисляется как a[i + 1] - a[i].